# Plotting Donut Chart with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I want to plot this two pie charts on the same plot. Below you can see my data:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)

    Share<- structure(list(Y = c(2018, 2018, 2019, 2019), Categorie = c("Before","After", "Before","After"), Share = c(1.0,99., 3, 97)), row.names = c(NA,-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I try with this lines of code but I can't find solution.

```
 fig1 <- plot_ly(Share, labels = ~Categorie , values = ~Share, type = 'pie')

 fig2 <- plot_ly(Share, labels = ~Categorie , values = ~Share, type = 'pie')
          
          
PLOT<-subplot(fig1,fig2,nrows=2,margin = 0.05)
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this and make plot like pic below  but with Donut Charts:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the following example to your data: [Placing donut charts side by side using plotly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436546/placing-donut-charts-side-by-side-using-plotly-in-r)

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(invisible(
    lapply(c("plotly", "dplyr"), require, character.only = TRUE)))

Share <- structure(list(Y = c(2018, 2018, 2019, 2019), 
                        Categorie = c("Before","After", "Before","After"), 
                        Share = c(1.0,99., 3, 97)), 
                   row.names = c(NA,-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

p <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_pie(data=Share, labels = ~Categorie , values = ~Share, hole = 0.6,
            name = "fig1", domain = list(x = c(0, 0.4), y = c(0.4, 1))) %>%
    add_pie(data=Share, labels = ~Categorie , values = ~Share, hole = 0.6,
            name = "fig2", domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1), y = c(0.4, 1)))  %>%
    layout(title = "Donut sub-plots", showlegend = TRUE,
           font=list(family="sans serif", color="#000"),
           plot_bgcolor="#f0f0f0",
           legend = list(orientation = 'h',font=list(size=28)),
           xaxis = list(title="", showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
           yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>